# How to find last modified file and it's timestamp no later than today?

Tags: perl, file, bash, awk, ls

I have a list of files named `filename.${date}`, for example `foo.20121102` and I want to print the last modified file that has the timestamp  up to today using bash toolset.

Comment: Do you need files up to 00:00 AM ? Or files from last 24 hours ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `shell` like you ask :

```
for i in *; do
    if stat -c %y "$i" | grep -q "^$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"; then
        echo "$i has been modified or created today"
    else
        echo "$i has NOT been modified or created today"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# 24 hours * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute
$threshhold = 86400;
$currenttime = time();
if( ($currenttime - $mtime) > $threshhold){
    # file was modified within 24 hours
}
```

for files modified after midnight lastnight:

```
if( $mtime > ($currenttime - ($currenttime % 86400)){
   # file was modified this calendar day
}
```

More information [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=85166)